# Google News - URLs scheme and Primary Key

Tags: php, mysql, database, seo

According to Google to allow your article/news to appear in Google News:

> Display a three-digit number. The URL
>   for each article must contain a unique
>   number consisting of at least three
>   digits. For example, we can't crawl an
>   article with this URL:
>   http://www.google.com/news/article23.html.
>   We can, however, crawl an article with
>   this URL:
>   http://www.google.com/news/article234.html.
>   Keep in mind that if the only number
>   in the article consists of an isolated
>   four-digit number that starts with 199
>   or 200, we won't be able to crawl it.
>   Please note that this rule is waived
>   with News sitemaps.

I have the following URL looking like this:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/news/91/this-is-news-title
```

This will not be accepted by google because News ID did not reach 119 or 200

So what can be done to change the primary key to start with 200? I already have 91 articles  (From ID 1 to 91).

Is there a way to change NewsID 1 become 200, NewsID 2 become 201. Also I need to add 301 Redirect for old article ID's to new ID's ?

My site is developed in PHP and News data from MySQL database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the SQL part, I guess you could do:

```
UPDATE news_table SET id=id+199 WHERE id<=91;
```

However, if Google has problems with isolated four-digit numbers that start with 199 or 200, you should probably begin at, say 2101. The relevant SQL update clause would then be:

```
UPDATE news_table SET id=id+2100 WHERE id<=91;
```

And for the redirecting part, assuming you are running Apache with `mod_rewrite`, something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/news/([0-9]{1})/(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/news/210$1/$2 [R=301, L]
RewriteRule ^/news/([0-9]{2})/(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/news/21$1/$2 [R=301, L]
```

Not 100% sure about these. Obviously you want to test all this in a development environment.

Answer (score 1):

Add leading zero's, so you'd have:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/news/091/this-is-news-title
```

Puting 091 instead of 91 will turn it into a 3-digit number, and crawlable.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Are you sure about this? I thought it need to be more than 119 or 200 according to google?